# Resize effect widthto in percentage

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, actionscript, effects

I have two container inside one main container. 
One container have 20% width and other container have 80% width. 
Now i want to hide 20% container on button click so i use.

```
<s:Resize id="resizeHide" widthTo="0" target="{fstContainer}"/>
```

Now, on same button click i want to resize that container by 20% then what will be the solution.

I tried following but didn't work for me.

```
<s:Resize id="resizeShow"  widthTo="20" target="{fstContainer}"/>
```

I cannot set fixed width. And resize effect will only take width in pixel.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To resize your container to 20% of your stage width, you can simply do like this :

Your `Resize` effect :

```
<s:Resize id="resizeShow" target="{fstContainer}"/>
```

And then for your button :

```
<s:Button id="btn_resize" label="Resize" click="resizeShow.widthTo = stage.stageWidth / 5; resizeShow.play();"/>
```

**EDIT :**

A 2nd manner, is to use the data binding, like this :

```
<s:Resize id="resizeShow" widthTo="{_20_percent}" target="{fstContainer}"/>
```

Declare the bindable var :

```
[Bindable] protected var _20_percent:Number;
```

And then, you can set its value when the creation of your app is completed, or when it's added to the stage, ... :

```
protected function on_addedToStage(event:Event):void
{
    _20_percent = stage.stageWidth / 5;
}

protected function on_creationComplete(event:FlexEvent):void
{
    // here of course, as you know, the stage is not yet accessible
    _20_percent = FlexGlobals.topLevelApplication.width / 5;
}
```

And of course, here you need to use only one event handler to set the value.

A 3rd manner, is to create your `Resize` effect dynamically when the user click the resize button :

```
protected function btn_resize_onClick(event:MouseEvent):void
{
    var resizeShow1:Resize = new Resize();
        resizeShow1.target = fstContainer;
        resizeShow1.widthTo = stage.stageWidth / 5;
        resizeShow1.play();
}
```

And it's to you to decide which manner you prefer ;)

Hope that can help.

Comment: Ohh sorry. my mistake i wrote wrong id of resize. Thanks a lot it's working. Is there any other solution for it Or this is the best solution?